# KendoUI - MVVM and Remote Datasource

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using remote datasource to populate the list from within Observable object as shown in code below.
On user creating a new entry for the list, I invoke a function within observable object.
To refresh the list with newly created entry, I read the first datasource for the second time as shown in code below.
The issue being, I don't see the newly added entry in the list even after the second read.
Thanks for your time and help.

```
 var viewModel = kendo.observable({
                postingsText: "",
                postings: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "http://localhost:8080/NavXzy/rest/SecurityService/getPostings?starId=3b583bed-fd29-4280-b1f2-c8485f323563"

                        }
                    }
                }),
                addPosting: function(e) {
                    var postingContent = this.get("postingsText");
                   if (postingContent) {
                        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                              transport: {
                                  read: {

                                        url: "http://localhost:8080/NavXzy/rest/SecurityService/posting",

                                        type: "POST",

                                        dataType: "json",

                                        data: { userStarId: "3b583bed-fd29-4280-b1f2-c8485f323563", postingText : postingContent }
                                    }
                              }
                        });
                        dataSource.read();
                     }
                    //refresh the list
                    this.postings.read();
                }

            });
            kendo.bind($("#postingsDiv"), viewModel);
```

Comment: Are you creating a new DataSource on each interaction? Why do not _replace_ the content instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an unusual way to insert a new record.
Normally you would have a "create" transport on your DataSource that specifies a URL to use to add items.

Something like:

```
            postings: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "http://localhost:8080/NavXzy/rest/SecurityService/getPostings?starId=3b583bed-fd29-4280-b1f2-c8485f323563"

                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "http://localhost:8080/NavXzy/rest/SecurityService/posting",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                    }
                }
            }),
            addPosting: function(e) {
                var postingContent = this.get("postingsText");
                if (postingContent) {
                    var itemToAdd = {
                        userStarId: "3b583bed-fd29-4280-b1f2-c8485f323563", 
                        postingText : postingContent
                    };
                    viewModel.postings.add(itemToAdd);
                }
            }
```

Then the act of adding an item to the DataSource will cause it to call the URL specified in `transport.create.url` and post your new item to the server. It will also raise a `change` event that will notify the UI to update to display the new record.

If the call to `.add()` doesn't cause an HTTP request to the best to the server, then add a call to `viewModel.postings.sync();` right after the call to `.add()`. Whether or not you need it depends on if `autoSync` is enabled on the DataSource.

---

My guess is that your original code did not work because `.read()` is asynchronous, so the 2nd read may have been happening before your 1st one finished.